# Not getting posted data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to be able to check if a user eamil exists on "blur()" with AJAX by posting the textbox data to php, i can see the data posted when i use firebug but i keep getting this error: Undefined index: data, i've tried so hard but haven't been able to resolve this issue yet.  This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#regEmail').blur(function() {
            var Email = $('#regEmail').val();
            var data = '{Email:' + Email + '}';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "register.php",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var result = response.exists;
                    if (result == true) {
                        alert('Email already exists!');
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Does not exist!");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

And this is the php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['data']))
    {
        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");

        $data = $_POST['data'];
        json_decode($data);

        $Email = $data->fetch_assoc();
        $Email = $Email["Email"];

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as isExisting FROM users WHERE user_email='$Email'"; 
        $sql_result = $db->query($sql);
        $result = $sql_result->fetch_assoc();

        if ($result["isExisting"] > 0)
        {
            $response = json_encode(array('exists' => true));
        } else {
            $response = json_encode(array('exists' => false));
        }

        echo $response;
        print json_encode($_POST);
    }
```

I added "if (isset($_POST['data']))" to check if the post data has been set but apparently it hasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` is for key/value formatted, URL encoded data. You're sending raw JSON which is different. With your current Javascript, you would need to use `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` to get the JSON on the PHP side.

This will do it:

```
        var data = { Email : Email };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "register.php",
            data: { data : JSON.stringify(data) },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var result = response.exists;
                if (result == true) {
                    alert('Email already exists!');
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Does not exist!");
                }
            }
        });
```

Changes:

- `data` variable to a Javascript object (not JSON)
- send as form encoded POST data, with one input (data) that is the JSON encoded version of the `data` object.
- removed the JSON content type

On the PHP side, your JSON will be decoded to an object, so use:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$email = json_decode($data);
$Email = $Email->Email;
```

You can use the array syntax, but only if you set the second argument for `json_decode()` to `true`. `json_decode()` does not update the variable passed as an argument, you must capture the return value.

Comment: This in fact did it, it got rid of the error but the javascript alert never pops up, could you please tell me why that is? I think the success bit doesn't get executed but i dunno why.

Comment: Delete `print json_encode($_POST);` from your PHP code. This is causing the response to be invalid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

With the jQuery.ajax method, the `data` parameter is supposed to be a JSON object.
You should write instead :

```
var data = { 'Email': Email };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "register.php",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var result = response.exists;
            if (result == true) {
                alert('Email already exists!');
                return;
            }
            else {
                alert("Does not exist!");
            }
        }
    }
);
```

And then you can use the email value server-side by accessing `$_POST['Email']`.

Comment: If you use `form` request style, then 'json' `content-type` is redundant.

Comment: If i do it like you suggested the email gets posted as "Email=xxxxxx%40gmail.com" instead of "Email=xxxxxx@gmail.com". And php still doesn't get the post.